# Making sure that objects in nibs are initialized before applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nib

and thanks for taking a look at my problem.

i have two view controllers in my app and each has its own nib file. an instance of controller1 is stored in MainWindow.xib and an instance of controller 2 is in Controller1.xib.

is there a way to make sure that controller 2 is initialized before the app delegate is sent applicationDiDFinishLaunching?

the actual setup is much more complicated with many other view controllers, so i really don't want to put everything into MainWindow.xib. plus doing so will reduce reusability.

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to make sure that controller 2 is initialized before the app delegate is sent `applicationDiDFinishLaunching`?

No. Well, maybe yes, but it's not how view controllers are supposed to work. The view controller is there to defer the loading of the nib, which is a rather expensive operation,  until the view is really, really necessary. So, if you need `controller2` right when `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called, you shouldn't put it inside the nib which is controlled by another view controller.

If I were you, I would stop instantiating the view controllers in the nib file at all, and just create them inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, as in

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
     ....
     self.controller2=[[Controller2 alloc] init... ];
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is the absolute entry point in which you have control of the code.  That's conceivably the earliest place to load anything.